# Git, undo merge commit on rebase

Tags: git, merge, rebase

I have a history which looks somewhat as following

```
  * (TOPIC) topic 3
  |
| * merge master onto topic
|/|
* | master 3
| * topic 2
* | master 2
| | 
| * topic 1
|/
* master 1
|
```

I.e. the upstream branch is merged into topic once. Now I want to interactively rebase this topic branch *on the same base*, but undo the merge (merge commit itself and all the commits from master introduced by the merge). How is this possible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Lets use valid identifiers for the commits depicted in your drawing:

```
  * topic3          (TOPIC) topic 3
  |
| * topic2merge     merge master onto topic
|/|
* | master3
| * topic2
* | master2
| | 
| * topic1
|/
* master1
|
```

If you want to remove the merge commit (make `topic2` the only parent of the first commit after `merge master onto topic`) you need to run the following [`git rebase`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase) command:

```
git rebase --onto topic2 topic2merge topic3
```

If the current branch is `topic3` already you can omit `topic3` from the command above (if it is present, the first thing that `git rebase` does it to it checkout, if it is not the current branch already).

After this operation, the graph look like this:

```
| * topic3      <-- (TOPIC) topic 3
| |
* | master3
| * topic2
* | master2
| | 
| * topic1
|/
* master1
|
```

The commits between and including `topic2merge` and `topic3` are still present in the repository but they are not visible any more. They are still visible if they are reachable and this happens if there are branches that points to them. Even remote branches.

If you have already pushed `topic3` to a remote repo you must run [`git push -f origin topic3`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push) (replace `origin` with the name of your remote) and inform your coworkers about the fact that you have changed history. They need to know this; on their repositories `topic3` still has `topic2merge` in its history and the change you did represents an alternative history line their repos do not take automatically. They have to use [`git reset --hard`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset) or [`git rebase`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase) or [`git cherry-pick`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick) to keep up.

Answer (score 7):

You can use command

```
git rebase -i --onto master1 master topic
```

This will take all non-merge commits which are in `topic` but not in `master` (which are topic1, topic2, topic3) and apply them on top of `master1` commit.